# How to enable Profiling under Microsoft Visual C++ 6.0

Tags: visual-c++, profile

I use Microsoft Visual C++ 6.0 For a particular project which I have, under the the "Project" tab, i see there is one menu - "Profile", but when I click on it, it says - Enable the profiling in project settings. So to "Enable Profiling", when I check under under Project Settings-->Link-->Category General-->Enable profiling seems to be disabled. I cannot check the check box there.

I have seen this profiling working under Microsoft Visual C++ 6.0 earlier where it gives CPU cycles consumed while running a program at end of its completiong.

How can i enable this profiling?

Does it need any extra file/dll to be copied in the installation folder of the tool or something?

thank you.

-AD

Comment: just to check it: you really mean the compiler m$ shipped in 1998?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you got the Standard edition of Visual C++?  Profiling is only supported in the Professional and Enterprise editions.

Comment: @Yes@ Standard Edition. That answers my problem. Thanks.